# Combine image data, row id and labels in one input file?

Tags: cntk

I have train / test input files in this format (filename label):

```
...\000881.JPG  2
...\000961.JPG  1
...\001700.JPG  1
...\001291.JPG  1
```

The input file above will be used with the ImageDeserializer. Since I have been unable to retrieve a row ID and the label from my code after the model have been trained, I created a second test file in this format:

```
|index 881 |piece_type 0 0 1 0 0 0
|index 961 |piece_type 0 1 0 0 0 0
|index 1700 |piece_type 0 1 0 0 0 0
|index 1291 |piece_type 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

The format of the second file is the same information as represented in the first file, but formatted differently. The index is the row number and the !piece_type is the label encoded in the one hot format. I need the file in the second format in order to be able to get to the row number and the label. The second file is used with the CTFDeserializer to create a composite reader like this:

```
image_source = ImageDeserializer(map_file, StreamDefs(
    features = StreamDef(field='image', transforms=transforms), # first column in map file is referred to as 'image'
    labels   = StreamDef(field='label', shape=num_classes)      # and second as 'label'
))

text_source = CTFDeserializer("test_map2.txt")
text_source.map_input('index', dim=1, format="dense")
text_source.map_input('piece_type', dim=6, format="dense")

# define a composite reader
reader_config = ReaderConfig([image_source, text_source])

minibatch_source = reader_config.minibatch_source()
```

The reason I have added the second file is to be able to create a confusion matrix and then I need to be able to have both the true labels and the predicted labels for a given minibatch that I test with. The row numbers are nice to have in order to get a pointer pack to the input images.

Would it be possible somehow to be able to do this with just one input file? It's bit of a hassle to deal with multiple files and formats.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does your file format for the second test file mean? Also: From your other questions I get that you are using the python interface - can you confirm? If you are using the CNTK commandline tool, there is a way to encode images, a unique example ID, and the label into one file. But before we get into that, please describe your setup more.

Comment: The format of the second file is the same information as represented in the first file, but formatted differently. The index is the row number and the !piece_type is the label encoded in the one hot format. I need the file in the second format in order to be able to get to the row number and the label, which I'm unable to get into my Python code by only using the first file format. You will understand what I mean, if you run through the CNTK_201B_CIFAR-10_ImageHandsOn and try to create a confusion matrix.

Comment: OK, now it makes a bit more sense. Can you edit your post a bit to clarify, with some of the information you put into the comment?

Answer (score 0):

You could load the test images without using a reader as described in [this wiki page](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Evaluate-a-saved-convolutional-network). Admittedly this puts the burden of all the transformations (cropping/mean subtraction etc.) to the user but at least the PIL package makes these easy. This [CNTK tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/v2.0.beta7.0/Tutorials/CNTK_205_Artistic_Style_Transfer.ipynb) uses PIL to crop and scale the input images before feeding them to CNTK.